# How to disable RecyclerView items in Android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-checkbox

Textviews and Checkboxes are in a Recyclerview. Initially all Checkboxes are selected. I want to prevent user changing Checkboxes state but I do not want to prevent Recyclerview scroll. I would like to do this in my fragment class not in adapter class.

How can I prevent user changing Checkboxes state?

Below is the sample code written in onBindViewHolder in adapter class.

```
holder.cbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            //set your object's last status
            tblFilm.setSelected(isChecked);
        }
    });
```

> The above code used for first mode which allows user clicks on
>   checkbox.
>
> After that I have second mode where I do not want to get clicked on
>   checkbox at all.

For that I have done is below.

```
optionsoff(recyclerView);
private static void optionsOff(ViewGroup layout) {
        layout.setEnabled(false);
        layout.setClickable(false);
        for (int i = 0; i < layout.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View child = layout.getChildAt(i);
            if (child instanceof ViewGroup) {
                optionsOff((ViewGroup) child);
            } else {
                child.setEnabled(false);
                child.setClickable(false);
            }
        }
```

I guess this `optionsoff()` is not working. Because it is not disabling the checkbox. I can still click on checkbox. I need help on this second method which is disabling the Recyclerview items.

Comment: What you have done so far?\

Comment: Currently RecyclerView displays 20 items which is film names and all respective checkboxes are selected by default. I want to prevent user clicking on checkbox.

Comment: so make it(Checkbox) as android:clickable="false" in your layout

Comment: @saurabhgupta pls check my updated question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every `CheckBox` has method [`setEnabled`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setEnabled(boolean)).

In [`onBindViewHolder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#onBindViewHolder(VH,%20int)) you can get the reference to the checkBox you want and disable it.

Something like this:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.checkBox.setEnabled(data.get(position).isEnabled());
}
```

Also an answer below is working solution through the xml.

Comment: Thanks for this but I want to do this in my fragment class not in adapter class.

Comment: @ShameemPayyanur Seems like you don't understand how it works. Fragment is a big view container with lifecycle. Adapter is thing, which is a bridge between your data and list representation. You can only change enable state of all items through the xml, like another answer, or using my way.

Answer (score 1):

Mayby try something like this?

```
<CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/server_is_online"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:text="@string/server_is_online"
        android:textSize="23sp" />
```

programmatically in your adapter (which extends BaseAdapter) you can add

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
            view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.rowbuttonlayout, null);
            final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.checkbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.check);
        } else {
            view = convertView;
            ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).checkbox.setTag(list.get(position));
        }
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        holder.checkbox.setChecked(true);
        holder.checkbox.setEnabled(false);
}
```

Good example of class extends BaseAdapter [here](http://android.amberfog.com/?p=296).

Comment: I want to do programmatically.